# How do I read from a file consists of city names and coordinates/Populations and create functions to get the coordinates and population?

Tags: python

I'm using Python, and I have a file which has city names and information such as names, coordinates of the city and population of the city:

> Youngstown, OH[4110,8065]115436
>   Yankton, SD[4288,9739]12011
>   966
>   Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826
>   1513 2410
>   Worcester, MA[4227,7180]161799
>   2964 1520 604
>   Wisconsin Dells, WI[4363,8977]2521
>   1149 1817 481 595

How can I create a function to take the city name and return a list containing the latitude and longitude of the given city?

```
fin = open ("miles.dat","r")
def getCoordinates 
cities = []
for line in fin:
    cities.append(line.rstrip())
    for word in line:
        print line.split()
```

That's what I tried now; how could I get the coordinates of the city by calling the names of the city and how can I return the word of each line but not letters?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: A little advice.. If you are very desperate and want a fast and helpful response, take just 30 more seconds when you are typing up your question to illustrate what you have attempted thus far, and an example of what you would like your expected result to be. The current state of your question asks people to produce a complete code solution for you from scratch, without even knowing really what format you are intending. I consider myself to be a little more forgiving than some others I see on here, but even I won't spend any of my time on this for you, as of yet.

Comment: I am writing it right now...thanks so much

Comment: This isn't even syntactically valid. Did you actually test this code?

Comment: Which part of those lines is the coordinate? [4227,7180] ? Or that line of numbers?

Comment: [4227,7180] is the coordinates...

Comment: @jdi, great advice. I'd also add that phraseology like "asap", "I'm desperate", "Looking forward to your speedy answer" are great ways to put people off helping (see all of those here!). Free/volunteer advice != immediately `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am feeling generous since you responded to my comment and made an effort to provide more info....

Your code example isn't even runnable right now, but from a purely pseudocode standpoint, you have at least the basic concept of the first part right. Normally I would want to parse out the information using a regex, but I think giving you an answer with a regex is beyond what you already know and won't really help you learn anything at this stage. So I will try and keep this example within the realm of the tools with which you seem to already be familiar.

```
def getCoordinates(filename):
    ''' 
    Pass in a filename.
    Return a parsed dictionary in the form of:

    {
        city:  [lat, lon]
    } 
    '''

    fin = open(filename,"r")
    cities = {}

    for line in fin:

        # this is going to split on the comma, and
        # only once, so you get the city, and the rest
        # of the line
        city, extra =  line.split(',', 1)

        # we could do a regex, but again, I dont think
        # you know what a regex is and you seem to already
        # understand split. so lets just stick with that

        # this splits on the '[' and we take the right side
        part = extra.split('[')[1]

        # now take the remaining string and split off the left
        # of the ']'
        part = part.split(']')[0]

        # we end up with something like: '4660, 12051'
        # so split that string on the comma into a list
        latLon = part.split(',')

        # associate the city, with the latlon in the dictionary
        cities[city] = latLong

    return cities
```

Even though I have provided a full code solution for you, I am hoping that it will be more of a learning experience with the added comments. Eventually you should learn to do this using the `re` module and a regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I know I havent done enough work to ask this question. I'm really new to python and I just don't know how to get started for some problems. Thanks so much for your help, I can work from here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Braybray: No problem. Make sure to hit the green checkmark ;-)

Comment: If lat,long is always a tuple of 2 4 digit numbers, the chances are they need to be divided by 100 to get latitude and longitude.  Also, I get latitude=42.2625932 longitude=-71.8022934 for Worcester, MA so for western hemisphere you need to use negative longitude.  If sometimes you have locations in eastern hemisphere you need to figure out a way to determine which hemisphere to get the correct (+ or -) longitude

Comment: Only jesus knows where his data is sourced from and what formats he is dealing with.