# So How could I get the coordinates and population of the city (retun them to a list) by calling the city names that are already created?

Tags: python, list, indexing, coordinates, slice

So this is the simplified version of the data file:

```
Wichita, KS[3769,9734]279835
308 1002 1270 1068 1344 1360 1220 944 1192 748 1618 1774 416 1054

Wheeling, WV[4007,8072]43070
1017 1247 269 255 1513 327 589 203 1311 416 627 605 2442 998 85

West Palm Beach, FL[2672,8005]63305
1167 1550 1432 965 1249 2375 1160 718 1048 2175 760 1515 1459 3280 1794 1252

Wenatchee, WA[4742,12032]17257
3250 2390 1783 1948 2487 2595 1009 2697 2904 2589 1394 2690 1765 2912 117 1461
2358

Weed, CA[4142,12239]2879
622 3229 2678 1842 1850 2717 2898 1473 2981 3128 2880 1858 2935 2213 3213 505
1752 2659

Waycross, GA[3122,8235]19371
2947 2890 360 820 1192 1097 605 904 2015 828 386 703 1815 413 1155 1127
2920 1434 899

Wausau, WI[4496,8964]32426
1240 2198 1725 1600 708 841 1138 805 913 848 1015 1222 907 646 1008 111
1230 1777 509 676

Waukegan, IL[4236,8783]67653
244 1000 2260 1933 1360 468 757 1023 565 673 1056 775 982 667 854 768
170 990 1985 551 436

Watertown, SD[4490,9711]15649
601 393 1549 1824 1351 1909 1058 572 880 1155 1263 534 1365 1572 1257 394
1358 433 1580 1403 156 1026
```

I can currently split the city and state name from the line. How can I get the coordinates of the city by calling the city names. How can i get the population of the city by calling city names? `[x,y]` is the coordinates and the number right after `[]` is the population.

And here is the code I have now:

```
fin = open("miles.txt","r")
cities=[]
for line in fin:
    A=line.split()
    if A[0][0] not in '0123456789':
        B= A[0] + A[1][0]+ A[1][1]   
        cities.append[B]
print cities
```

Thanks! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Exact, and [I mean exact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834366/how-i-could-split-the-state-name-and-append-it-together-with-the-city-name-so-th) duplicate.

Comment: yes...sorry I just didnt know how to change the title so I asked an another one...

Comment: I understand entirely. Stick with this site. You'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Duplicate here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826669/how-do-i-read-from-a-file-consists-of-city-names-and-coordinates-populations-and. He is basically constantly reposting the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse_cities(fin):
    cities = {}
    distances = {}
    order = []
    index = 0
    valid_city = False
    for line in fin:
        if '[' in line:  # city line
            # .partition() will always return three strings
            citystate, left, rest = line.partition('[')
            coordinates, right, population = rest.partition(']')
            lat, comma, lng = coordinates.partition(',')

            # drop any surrounding whitespace
            citystate = citystate.strip()
            lat = lat.strip()
            lng = lng.strip()
            population = population.strip()

            # validity check
            valid_city = (
                # delimiters must exist
                left and right and comma and
                # numbers must be valid
                lat.isdigit() and lng.isdigit() and population.isdigit()
            )

            if not valid_city: continue

            order.append(citystate)
            cities[citystate] = (int(lat), int(lng), int(population))
            index = 0
        elif line and line[0].isdigit() and valid_city:  # distance line
            # citystate variable from previous iteration
            # index variable will be reset for each new city,
            #     but otherwise increase between the lines
            for dist in [int(w) for w in line.split()]:
                if index >= len(order): break
                citystate2 = order[index]
                distances[citystate,citystate2] = dist
                distances[citystate2,citystate] = dist
                index += 1
    return cities, distances
```

```
with open("miles.txt","r") as fin:
    cities, distances = parse_cities(fin)
print cities['Waycross, GA'] # (3122, 8235, 19371)
print distances['Youngstown, OH', 'Yakima, WA'] # 1513
```

Comment: Mizard...thanks so much for you response..I just have two questions....what if I want to create 2 different functions to return population, coordinates respectively?

Comment: And if the data looks like this:Youngstown, OH[4110,8065]115436
Yankton, SD[4288,9739]12011
966
Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826
1513 2410
Worcester, MA[4227,7180]161799
2964 1520 604
Wisconsin Dells, WI[4363,8977]2521
1149 1817 481 595
Winston-Salem, NC[3610,8025]131885
927 729 2742 1289 494
Winnipeg, MB[4988,9715]564473
1611 686 1833 1446 550 1279
Winchester, VA[3919,7816]20217
1510 290 826 466 2641 1197 250
Wilmington, NC[3424,7792]139238
390 1823 214 1139 765 2956 1500 637

Comment: like...966 will be the distance between Youngstown and Tankton...1513 will be the distance from yakima to yanton, 2410 from yakima to youngstown....How to creat a function that takes two city names and returns the distance between
the two cities?   Thanks......@MizardX